# Is a prefix any set of letters that could be the beginning of a word?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, prefixes

For example, is it accurate to say that *unac* is a prefix of *unacceptable*, or is *un* the only valid prefix?

If it is not a prefix is there a word for what *unac* would be in the above case?

Comment: A prefix is a [morpheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme), which by definition is *not* just any set of letters.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Your second question ("Is there a word for this?") is fine IMHO, so my guess would be that the downvotes are due to the first question ("Is a prefix any set of letters...?") being too basic, as you could have easily looked up the answer on Wikipedia, say, or perhaps even just in a dictionary. I wouldn't take that personally (and it's still a net win for you reputation-wise), but perhaps as something to keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A prefix is a group of letters that appear at the beginning of a word AND that carry a meaning that modifies the meaning of that word.

So in "unacceptable", "un-" is a prefix that means "not", so "unacceptable" means "not acceptable". Or for example in "antisocial", "anti-" is a prefix meaning "against", so someone who is "antisocial" is "against being social". Etc.

I don't know of any general term for an arbitrary number of beginning letters on a word. Perhaps "leading letters"?

Answer (score 1):

The word "unacceptable" consists of three parts: **un · accept · able**.

*Un-* is the negative prefix, *accept* is the stem, and *-able* is the suffix.

So, *unac* is not a prefix and it is meaningless by itself.